# llvm-link error when using memcpy in C code and compiling with wasm target

Tags: clang, llvm, webassembly

I am trying to compile two *.c files to LLVM bitcode via `clang`, link them together using `llvm-link`, and make a single *.wasm file out of it. I built LLVM on my machine via the Makefile provided by https://github.com/yurydelendik/wasmception

This works fine until I use `memcpy` in the C code. Then `llvm-link` stops with error:

```
Intrinsic has incorrect argument type!
void (i8*, i8*, i32, i1)* @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i32
```

The following is a minimal example to reproduce the issue:

one.c

```
#define EXPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#include <string.h>

char* some_str();

EXPORT void do_something() {
  char* cpy_src = some_str();
  char other_str[15];
  memcpy(other_str, cpy_src, strlen(cpy_src));
}
```

two.c

```
char* some_str() {
  return "Hello World";
}
```

Execute the following commands:

```
$ clang --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown-wasm --sysroot=../wasmception/sysroot -S -emit-llvm -nostartfiles -fvisibility=hidden one.c -o one.bc
[...]
$ clang --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown-wasm --sysroot=../wasmception/sysroot -S -emit-llvm -nostartfiles -fvisibility=hidden two.c -o two.bc
[...]
```

Note that no optimization is done because that would eliminate the unnecessary `memcpy` call here. As I said, this is a minimal example out of context to show the error.

```
$ llvm-link one.bc two.bc -o res.bc -v
Loading 'one.bc'
Linking in 'one.bc'
Loading 'two.bc'
Linking in 'two.bc'
Intrinsic has incorrect argument type!
void (i8*, i8*, i32, i1)* @llvm.memcpy.p0i8.p0i8.i32
llvm-link: error: linked module is broken!
```

When I comment out the `memcpy` call in the example file, the error is gone. Of course this is not an option in the real project I am working at.

Am I doing something wrong? Is it a bad idea in general to use `memcpy` in a WebAssembly context? Can this be a bug in LLVM/Clang?

Comment: As a workaround, you could try disabling memcpy intrinsic expansion with `-fno-builtin`

Comment: Reading this (https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues/1003), it may be that memcpy intrinsic is not yet supported, but I don't know for sure

Comment: Woah dude. That did the trick! `-fno-builtin` makes the error disappear. Thank you. @valiano If you post it as an answer I'll accept and upvote.

Comment: Thanks @Steve Beer, glad that helped!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading through these github issues, it seems the `memcpy` intrinsic is not currently supported by the WASM backend:

https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues/236
https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues/1003

As a workaround, you could instruct clang to disable intrinsic expansion using `-fno-builtin`, so that the generated code will call the actual `memcpy` function.

Comment: While the workaround did in fact make my example work, it did not eliminate all intrinsic function calls in the real project I am fiddling around with. I will investigate a bit more and maybe post another question. For now, this answer is still a good one for me, b/c it solves the problem with the given example.

Comment: Thanks so much! This helped me when I just wanted to use the standard C library for C to WASM compilation; In certain cases, it would try to optimize by using library functions like memcpy when I'd never added it, and so compilation would fail (at least, I think that's what was going on).